# CSS two column fit on specific width

Tags: html, css

I have a question, have been trying to solve this for a while now

I am having a hard time making my columns align.

Especially when I specific a width of 1010px, but have a border of 20px...
so the overall thing becomes 1010px...

Single columns have no problem, but when I have two column, the second one gets pushed to the bottom if I don't play with the number(Under Top News and Comments). I wish I can just scale down the comment part.

Hope this is an easy fix... I've been trying everything including width:100% and position:fixed... Just can't get it to align perfectly...

In Summery:
Site is here: http://ecommerce.omgppl.com/
Two columns are "Top News" and "Comments"
Cannot get two columns to line up with the column above. All columns have 960px with 20px border and 5px margin left and right.

Comment: We will need to see the css as well as the HTML to have any hope of helping you.

Answer (score 0):

Now I cannot get exactly what you are saying, I'm going to try this for you though, I recommend you set the `position` of both columns to `absolute` instead of `fixed`. The problem with `relative` and `fixed` for positioning any `<div>` is the browser will take the code and read it as if you wanted to place the divs in order of how they are coded in the code instead of exactly where you wanted them. When you set the `position` to `fixed` it only will fix it to the point the browser decides is correct. So say you scroll down the page, it will slide down the page with you, making it look as if it were pinned to your browser.

**Update:** Understand that your issue is very common, if I had two more reputation points I would upvote it just because I think a lot of people have this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try changing code as follows

```
.container_12{
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 1025px !important;
}

#subcontent2 .container_12 .grid_9, #subcontent2 .container_12 .grid_3 {
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    border: 25px solid rgb(241, 196, 15);
}
.container_12 .grid_9{
    width: 650px;
}
```